# JSON Schema for objects without names

Tags: python, json, schema, jsonschema

I want to write part of a schema that validates a list of objects, where the objects in the list don't have a name:

```
"some list": [
    {
        "thing 1": "foo",
        "thing 2": 100
    },
    {
        "thing 1": "foo",
        "thing 2": 100
    },
    {
        "thing 1": "foo",
        "thing 2": 100
    },
]
```

I have a working schema that has the extra key name that I want to get rid of, labelled `I WANT TO GET RID OF THIS NAME`. I guess you could think of it as not having a property name for that object.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "id": "v2",
    "properties": {
        "some list": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "I WANT TO GET RID OF THIS NAME": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "thing 1": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "description": "a string"
                            },
                            "thing 2": {
                                "type": "integer",
                                "minimum": 0,
                                "description": "Default time to expose a single image layer for."
                            }
                        },
                        "additionalProperties": false
                    },
                    "additionalProperties": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't just git rid of the name because the schema spec expects it, but I also can't figure out how to tell it those objects don't have a name. I am running this example with Python 3.7 using `jsonschema Draft7Validator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are correct to get rid of that property - it is referring to the wrong level of nesting. the schema should look like:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "id": "v2",
  "properties": {
    "some list": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "thing 1": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "a string"
          },
          "thing 2": {
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 0,
            "description": "Default time to expose a single image layer for."
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I realized I actually removed the wrong name when looking at this. I really wanted to get rid of the names for `"thing 1"` and `"thing 2"`. I'll post a new question with it, if you know how to fix it, go take a look